# Несколько INT в одном поле mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Могу ли я хранить несколько значений INT в одном поле в mysql?

Comment: Могу лишь предложить хранить массив int значений в одной ячейке. Но придётся писать функцию для извлечения

Comment: да, тоже об этом думал

Comment: Вы бы сказали зачем это надо. а то по этим "массивам" потом пытаются что то найти или еще что то с ними сделать и оказывается, что надо делать по НФ вынося в отдельную таблицу

Answer (score 1):

Нет. В ячейки типа `int` можно хранить только одно целое число. 

UPD: для хранения можно использовать массивы (Как было сказано выше).

Comment: Массивы в MySQL .... это что то новенькое. можно конечно в текст сериализовать массив но работать с ним будет крайне тяжело

Comment: @Mike, ничего тяжёлого в этом нет. Массив в php, а в MySQL это string из переменных через запятую

Comment: Ну я и говорю сериализовать в текст. Только у нас тут на SO масса вопросов "у меня вот тут значения через запятую, а я хочу по ним ссылочную целостность проверять и искать еще хочу и что бы при этом like не перебирал всю таблицу, а быстренько по индексу находил в миллионах строк". поэтому и говорю, что тяжело, для БД тяжело, like то написать не долго ...

Comment: Так вы лучше скажите как лучше реализовать

Comment: На самом деле Вам сказали, в комментарии к Вашему вопросу: "надо делать по НФ вынося в отдельную таблицу", все остальное извращения ( в mysql по крайней мере, если бы речь шла о postgresql, это был бы другой разговор), которые в перспективе ни во что хорошее не выльются. С другой стороны действительно лучше опишите задачу, зачем Вам оно надо, тогда действительно можно будет порекомендовать что-то отталкиваясь от Вашего конкретного случая.

Comment: В 5.7.7 добавили поддержку JSON, на русском тут - http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/20.html